# Select2 search won't return the result

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I'm having problem with the search when it Ajax load from json. Let's say I search for Yemen, the Yemen record won't be selected or highlighted.

Here's the full source, any setting not done correctly?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('#allowedCountries').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select allowed countries',
        allowClear:true, 
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        ajax: {
            dataType : "json",
            url      : "countries2.json",
        },
    });    
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
for select2<Br>

<div style="width:100%">
    <select name="allowedCountries" class="js-states form-control" id="allowedCountries"><option></option></select>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Then for json file, sample data

```
{
    "results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Aland Islands"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": 245,
        "text": "Yemen"
    },
    {
        "id": 246,
        "text": "Zambia"
    },
    {
        "id": 247,
        "text": "Zimbabwe"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling quickly through the official documentation, could this be a problem?

[image]